# foldr - further explanation and example with a map function

Tags: haskell, fold

I've looked at different folds and folding in general as well as a few others and they explain it fairly well.

I'm still having trouble on how  it would work in this case.

```
length :: [t] -> Int
length list = foldr (+) 0 (map (\x ->1) list)
```

Could someone go through that step by step and try to explain that to me.

And also how would foldl work as well.

Comment: What exactly is unclear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(map (\x ->1) list)` takes the list and turns it into a list of `1` values:

```
(map (\x ->1) ["a", "b", "c"]) == [1, 1, 1]
```

Now, if you substitute that in the original foldr, it looks like this:

```
foldr (+) 0 [1, 1, 1]
```

The starting point is `0` and the aggregation function is `(+)`. As it steps through each element in the list, you are basically adding up all the `1` values, and that's how you end up returning the length.

`foldr` starts from the right and works back to the head of the list. `foldl` starts from the left and works through the list. Because the aggregation function is `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`, the ordering of the left and right arguments in `(+)` is logically inconsequential (with the caveat that `foldl` has stack overflow problems with large lists because of lazy evaluation)

Comment: and whts the difference please when we use length = foldr (\x n -> n + 1) 0 ?

Comment: If you use `foldr (\_ n -> n + 1) 0 list`, you don't need to first map to a list of the value `1`, since your lambda ignores the value in the list and sums a hardcoded `1`.